# Boolean is always 'True'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

```
import random
die1=''
die2=''
throw=''
player=''

play=(input("Would you like to play?"))

if play == "Yes" or "yes":
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    throw = (die1+die2)
    print(throw)

else:
    print("Thanks anyways!")
```

I've been staring at my code for about an hour and I cannot figure out what I have done wrong. Line 9 always comes out as 'True' regardless of the conditional actually being True or not. Could someone please spot what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is evaluated in the following way.

```
(play == "Yes") or bool("yes")
```

You want it to be

```
play == "Yes" or play == "yes"
```

Otherwise if `play != "Yes"`, the truthiness of `"yes"` is evaluated and non-empty strings are truthy.

A more general case that covers all combinations of lower and uppercases would be to use this.

```
play.lower() == "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

"yes" is cast as True. What you need to do is do if play == "Yes" or play == "yes"

Answer (score 0):

This is how the python interprets `play == 'Yes' or 'yes'` so when you actually run it in the terminal you see the output as `yes` and not True or False as when you do `or` it checks first condition which might be false in your case but then it gives `yes` which is non empty string which is treated as True value in python.

So to overcome this problem adding on top of @Oiver's answer

you can change the line to

1. `if play == 'Yes' or play == 'yes':`
2. `if play in ['Yes', 'yes']:`

this should fix the problem.

Comment: modified the snippet